# Servicestack accessing json

Tags: servicestack

My Servicestack service is beeing posted Json (by jquery).

```
sendData = function(dataToSend) {
  var request;
  return request = $.ajax({
    url: "/api/test",
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
    dataType: "json",
    accept: "application/json",
    contentType: "application/json"
  });
```

The Json data is correctly deserialized if it corresponds to the root properties of my DTO (eg: userId:'foo' -> UserId=foo in the DTO).

I want to access the raw json posted data before it gets deserialized for adding custom deserialization.
Till now I had no problems accessing the querystrings with custom filters  (RequestFilterAttribute) or if data vas posted like form.
Now I see the data that gets posted with Chrome Developer Tools is in the headers with "Request Payload"  so it is nor in FormData and nor QueryString I can access when debugging my IHttpRequest. 
How can I get my raw json data in the filter?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to access the raw request body data, before ServiceStack attempts to deserialize it into a requset DTO object?

Comment: Yes exactly. If I post with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded I can see the data when I debug in the filter attribute code, also if I use GET instead of POST I see it in the querystring parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace the default deserialization behavior with custom behavior for a specific request DTO, you can do this in your AppHost setup code:

```
JsConfig<MyRequestDtoClass>.DeSerializeFn = DeserializeMyRequestDto;
```

Where `DeserializeMyRequestDto` is a function or lambda taking a single string param - the raw request body - and returning the deserialized instance of your DTO:

```
MyRequestDtoClass DeserializeMyRequestDto(string rawBody) { ... }
```

RequestFilterAttribute subclasses purpotedly have access to the raw request body using `request.GetRawBody()`, where `request` is the `IHttpRequest` object passed into the filter's `Execute` method. But in my experience, `GetRawBody` returns an empty string, because the request input stream seems to be consumed by that time due to the deserialization. I worked around this once by creating an HTTP module (registered in AppHost via `DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule`) that would "peek" at the request input stream in a `BeginRequest` event handler. (The "peek" function would read the request input stream and then reset the `Position` of the stream to where it initially was.)