# ServiceStack PreRequestFilters vs RequestFilters

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am looking at `AppHostBase.cs` and it has the following:

```
//....
public IContentTypeFilter ContentTypeFilters {
    get {return EndpointHost.ContentTypeFilter;}
}
public List<Action<IHttpRequest, IHttpResponse>> PreRequestFilters {
    get {return EndpointHost.RawRequestFilters;}
}
public List<Action<IHttpRequest, IHttpResponse, object>> RequestFilters {
    get {return EndpointHost.RequestFilters;}
}   
public List<Action<IHttpRequest, IHttpResponse, object>> ResponseFilters {
    get {return EndpointHost.ResponseFilters;}
}
//....
```

I read from the SS website document and know what is `RequestFilters` and `ResponseFilters`. But why is there a `PreRequestFilter` seperated from `RequestFilters`? What is it for?

I google'd around and see an example of SignalR code written in `PreRequestFilters` why not just write it in `RequestFilters` what is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Order of Operations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations), Pre-Request Filters are executed before the DTO is deserialized, and regular RequestFilters are executed after that. Also note that request filters are executed in a specific order depending on whether they are implemented as Attributes or registered via AppHost, and also based on the Priority of the request filter attributes.

Comment: Thanks :) also found this: "ASP.NET Requests are by default forward-only, this means that the Request body can only be read once, either by ServiceStack or yourself manually. The lastest version of ServiceStack supports IHttpRequest.UseBufferedStream which you can set using a pre-request filter that tells ServiceStack to keep a buffer of the request body so it can be re-read. This will let you call base.Request.GetRawBody() from inside your service so you can parse the JSON dynamically with JsonObject.Parse() which parses the JSON into a dictionary so you can determine what keys are present."

Comment: Excellent find. I previously had to write some custom code to ["peek" at the request body stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919853/servicestack-accessing-json/18006142#18006142) in a pre-request filter and then reset the stream so that deserialization wouldn't break. Looks like I may be able to greatly simplify that code with `UseBufferedStream`.